# How to use runOnUiThread() or onPostExecute() to update the UI within a thread

Tags: java, android

I have a class ConnectionThread that extends Thread. I am passing the context to it's constructor and i want to invoke a method that enables and disables all the buttons on the UI. This method is in the same class - ConnectionThread. Also i want to popup a Toast in a try catch block in case the connection can't be established.

```
public ConnectionThread(Context context, BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket,
        Button connectButton, Button disconnectButton,
        Button throttleUpButton, Button throttleDownButton,
        Button moveForwardButton, Button moveBackwardButton,
        Button moveLeftButton, Button moveRightButton, Button exitButton) {
```

My question is how can i use runOnUiThread() or onPostExecute() to do that?

Answer (score 2):

`onPostExecute()`(only in `Asynctask`) runs already on UI thread so no need to create a `runOnUiThread` inside of it.. In other case if you are inside a thread or background task and want to update some views now you need to call the `runOnUiThread` because you are now leaving the main thread..

pass the activity instance to the contructor to call the main thread.

**example:**

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //code here
  }
});
```

Comment: `Context` does not have the `runOnUiThread` method, `Activity` does.

Comment: The other problem is how to show an AlertDialog with one EditText field withing the thread. How can i do that? About the problem with showing a Toast i solved it by creating a static method that calls Toast inside the Controller class and i successfully invoked it in the thread.

Comment: @TedTedson you mean the layout of the Alert dialog?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin So to use runOnUiThread within an Activity class, do I need to set  up the instance like this:  "Activity activity = MainActivity.this;"?

Comment: @AJW If you are calling it within the activity you can just emit an extra call to the activity's instance. Instead, you can call directly the method itself since it is part of the activity class.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin  Ok, can you please provide examples for the two calls you are mentioning?

Comment: @AJW If you are calling in the activity you can call: `runOnUiThread()`

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use `Thread`, use `AcyncTask`. It's a thread + Android-specific thread lifecycle boilerplate:

```
class ConnectionThread extends AsyncTask<Argument, Integer, Result> {

     protected Result doInBackground(Argument... args) {
         du stuff here
         return result;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // called in UI thread
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
         // called in UI thead
     }
 }
```

But honestly, that's a bad design decision. You must keep in mind that the activity can be destroyed at any time and running task may report back to invalid Activity, forcing you to manaully do the housekeeping: registering/unregistering listeners, keeping valid/invalid flags, stuff like that.

There are A LOT of libraries to do asynchronous tasks civilized way, such as:

1. RoboSpice: https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice
2. Official `Loader` API will save you tons of problems too.
3. Volley
4. DataDroid (obsolete, but still can be found in many projects)

Alternatively you can move your long-running tasks to a `Service` and keep worker threads there. `Activity` can bind to a `Service` and unbind from it, keeping your application logic decoupled from the UI.

Pushing all app logic into the `Activity is the major source of PITA in Android apps across the board. I have no idea why Google is promoting such bad practices. It looks nice and simple in tutorials (that's a PR move maybe?), but doing anything beyond hello-world ends up in endless Activity lifecycle debugging sessions.

TL;DR

1. Use RoboSpice, `Loader` or similar solution
2. Use `Service`s
3. Forget about Thread, AsyncTask only in the simplest cases

Comment: Thanks, and what about button.post()? I want the simplest way with fewer code. Also i want to notify the user if bluetoothSocket.connect() has failed. So i should invoke Toast. There should be a simple solution, i just want to enable and disable some buttons and invoke a popup, nothing more.

Comment: As I said, the activity you refer to may be no longer visible on the screen. Of course, since you keep a reference to the Context in the AsyncTask it won't be garbage collected, so you will NOT experience `NullPointerException`. It will simply set a button that is no longer visible on the screen.

Comment: I won't say that `button.post()` won't work. It will for the simplest cases. Anything beyond "simplest" will rapidly make your code a spaghetti.

Comment: The other problem is how to show an AlertDialog with one EditText field withing the thread. How can i do that? About the problem with showing a Toast i solved it by creating a static method that calls Toast inside the Controller class and i successfully invoked it in the thread.

Comment: What is the purpose of that dialog? Do you want to pass user response back to the thread?

Comment: The dialog will have password input field and it must be send to the other side by the thread. The response is OK or ERROR, it should be retrieved and if it is OK all the buttons should be enabled otherwise the socket should be closed. I am trying to solve the problem with a public static boolean isPasswordAccepted. The variable belonds to the Controller class and it will be modified by the thread. I hope that will work, i will try it tomorrow may be. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

views all have the very handy `post` method that does the same as `Activity.runOnUiThread`:

```
connectButton.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // TODO Update your UI here
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the post() method more efficient to run versus the Activity instance's runOnUIThread()?

Comment: both do the same thing: post a runnable on the ui thread execution queue.